# Woocommerce template update

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I inherited a website with a child theme. This child theme has a Woocommerce folder overriding the parent's theme. I'm now getting a lot of warnings about obsolete templates. I have done this process before of comparing the templates side by side but this time around I'm finding that the templates are extremly different. For example, this is the newest woocommerce "content-single-product.php":

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_single_product hook.
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     */
     do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

     if ( post_password_required() ) {
        echo get_the_password_form();
        return;
     }
?>

<div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .summary -->

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

And this is what I have in this theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content in the single-product.php template
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

$l = et_page_config();

$layout = etheme_get_option('single_layout');

$image_class = 'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'; 
$infor_class = 'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'; 

if($layout == 'small') {
    $image_class = 'col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12'; 
    $infor_class = 'col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12'; 
}

if($layout == 'large') {
    $image_class = 'col-sm-12'; 
    $infor_class = 'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'; 
}


if($layout == 'fixed') {
    $image_class = 'col-sm-6'; 
    $infor_class = 'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12'; 
}

?>

<?php

    $class = 'tabs-'.etheme_get_option('tabs_location');
    $class .= ' single-product-'.$layout;
    $class .= ' reviews-position-'.etheme_get_option('reviews_position');
    if(etheme_get_option('ajax_addtocart')) $class .= ' ajax-cart-enable';

    /**
     * woocommerce_before_single_product hook
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     */
     do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

     if ( post_password_required() ) {
        echo get_the_password_form();
        return;
     }

    if(!etheme_get_option('product_name_signle')) {
        $class .= ' hide-product-name';
    }
?>

<div itemscope itemtype="<?php echo woocommerce_get_product_schema(); ?>" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($class); ?>>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="<?php esc_attr_e( $l['content-class'] ); ?> product-content sidebar-position-<?php esc_attr_e( $l['sidebar'] ); ?>">
            <div class="row">
                <?php if ($layout == 'fixed'): ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 product-summary-fixed">
                        <div class="fixed-product-block">
                            <div class="fixed-content">
                                <?php 
                                    woocommerce_template_single_title();
                                    woocommerce_template_single_rating();
                                    echo '<hr class="divider short">';
                                    woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
                                    echo do_shortcode('[share title="'.__('Share Social', ET_DOMAIN).'" text="'.get_the_title().'"]');
                                 ?>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                <div class="<?php esc_attr_e( $image_class ); ?> product-images">
                    <?php
                        /**
                         * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook
                         *
                         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
                         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
                         */
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
                    ?>
                </div><!-- Product images/ END -->

                <?php 
                    if($layout == 'large') {
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <?php
                    } 
                ?>

                <div class="<?php esc_attr_e( $infor_class ); ?> product-information">
                    <div class="product-information-inner <?php if($layout == 'fixed') echo 'fixed-product-block' ?>">
                        <div class="fixed-content">
                            <?php if(!etheme_get_option('product_name_signle')):  ?>
                                <h4 class="title"><?php _e('Product Information', ET_DOMAIN); ?></h4>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php
                                /**
                                 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
                                 *
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5 
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
                                 */
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
                            ?>

                            <?php if(etheme_get_option('share_icons') && $layout != 'fixed') echo do_shortcode('[share title="'.__('Share Social', ET_DOMAIN).'" text="'.get_the_title().'"]'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- Product information/ END -->
                <?php 
                    if($layout == 'large') {
                        ?>
                            <div class="<?php esc_attr_e( $infor_class ); ?>">
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    } 
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20 [REMOVED in woo.php]
                 */
                 if(etheme_get_option('tabs_location') == 'after_content' && $layout != 'large') {
                     do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
                 }
            ?>

        </div> <!-- CONTENT/ END -->


        <?php if($l['sidebar'] != '' && $l['sidebar'] != 'without' && $l['sidebar'] != 'no_sidebar'): ?>
            <div class="<?php esc_attr_e( $l['sidebar-class'] ); ?> single-product-sidebar sidebar-<?php esc_attr_e( $l['sidebar'] ); ?>">
                <?php et_product_brand_image(); ?>
                <?php if(etheme_get_option('upsell_location') == 'sidebar') woocommerce_upsell_display(); ?>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar('single-sidebar'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if(etheme_get_option('upsell_location') == 'after_content') woocommerce_upsell_display(); ?>
    <?php
        if(etheme_get_custom_field('additional_block') != '') {
            echo '<div class="product-extra-content">';
                et_show_block(etheme_get_custom_field('additional_block'));
            echo '</div>';
        }     
    ?>
    <?php if(etheme_get_option('show_related')) woocommerce_output_related_products(); ?>


    <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />

</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Of course using the newest Woocommerce makes the shop look nothing like it did so how should I proceed in a case like this?

Answer (score 0):

The outdated files are in your child theme's woocommerce folder.If you purchased the theme you could also contact their support and see about purchasing an upgrade because if the theme has been updated for compatibility.

If there were important customizations in your templates then begins the super-fun job of comparing the old templates to the new ones (which are in the plugin WooCommerce's templates folder).Open the template you pasted into the theme folder with a text editor of choice, such as Notepad++, and replicate any changes that you had to the previous template in your new, updated template file.

I found answer from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152930/how-do-i-update-woocommerce-template-files-in-my-theme